# JSON.parse works with array with zero elements (node.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, parsing

According to the documentation [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) takes first argument as a string.
I found an unexpected behaviour:

```
try {
    const a = JSON.parse([
        '{"helloworld": 1}',
    ]);
    console.log(a);
} catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
}
```

I expected it to fail as the provided input argument is an array. In contrast, `JSON.parse` successfully parses array[0] element an prints it out (in node.js).

However, if you pass array with two elements, `JSON.parse` will error out

```
try {
    const b = JSON.parse([
        '{"hello": 1}',
        '{"hello2": 2}',
    ]);
    console.log(b);
} catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
}
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse is an internal JS method that expects a string. However, if the other type is given, it will convert it to string. For an array the conversion to string is `array.join(',')`.

Therefore, when having one element, it will just convert first element to string. When providing an array with more than one element to JSON.parse, it will error out as the input JSON won't be valid.

Comment: Depends on what's in the array... technically something like `['{"hello": 1', '"hi":2}']` would be valid... :P

Comment: true :) but I wouldn't suggest doing that to avoid OMGs from other devs